# Error: ‘fp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]

Tags: c, file, pointers, initialization, variable-assignment

I am relatively new to using files in C. Today, when I was working on my program, when I declared a FILE pointer and tried to utilize it,
I keep getting this error:

```
answer3.c:44:5: error: ‘fp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
   if(fp == NULL)
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Here is my code

```
bool  runIntegrate(char * infilename, char * outfilename)
    // return true if it can successfully open and read the input 
    // and open and write the output
    // return false when encountering any problem
    {
      Integration intrg;
      FILE * fp;
      fopen(infilename,"r");
      // open the input file name for reading
      // if fopen fails, return false
      if(fp == NULL)
       {
        fclose(fp);
        return false;            
       }
      
      if (fscanf(fp,"%lf\n", &intrg.lowerlimit) != 1){
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
      }
```

I am pretty sure I have the formatting correct, so I am not too sure what the issue seems to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What don't you understand? Where do you assign a value to `fp`? I think you meant to assign the result of `fopen()` to it.

Comment: `fp = fopen(infilename,"r");`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You've not assigned a value to `fp* before you use it in your `if` statement. *formatting* is irrelevant - you could write the code as a single line without any formatting and you still wouldn't be assigning a value to `fp`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the returned value of the call of the function fopen to the pointer `fp`

```
  FILE * fp;
  fopen(infilename,"r");
  // open the input file name for reading
  // if fopen fails, return false
  if(fp == NULL)
  //...
```

Thus the pointer `fp` stays uninitialized.

Instead write

```
  FILE * fp = fopen(infilename,"r");
  // open the input file name for reading
  // if fopen fails, return false
  if(fp == NULL)
```

Pay attention to that it is better to declare the function parameters with the qualifier `const` because they are not being changed within the function

```
bool  runIntegrate( const char * infilename, const char * outfilename)
```